# Debian "unable to allocate memory"

Tags: linux, debian, asterisk

I have Debian jessie installed.

kernel version:

> > Linux srv1 3.16-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.5-1 (2014-10-10) x86_64 GNU/Linux

It has 32Gb memory installed. It seems more then enough for my task.
Heavy utilized asterisk process leak a lot of memory and produce a lot of troubles.

> > Asterisk itself and bash from time to time reports  "unable to allocate memory".

At the same time based on attached top report server has 7 Gb unused memory.

It will be great if someone will help to figure out what is wrong: 
- what kind of resources were exhausted 
- what need to be tuned for 100% server resources utilization.

### **Top:**

Tasks: 130 total,   1 running, 129 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
   %Cpu0  :  6,0 us,  1,3 sy,  0,0 ni, 21,5 id, 70,8 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,3 si,  0,0 st
   %Cpu1  : 70,2 us,  0,3 sy,  0,0 ni, 24,8 id,  4,6 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
   %Cpu2  :  3,0 us,  0,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 84,6 id, 11,7 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
   %Cpu3  :  6,9 us,  0,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 78,2 id, 14,2 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
   %Cpu4  :  3,3 us,  0,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 84,3 id, 11,7 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
   %Cpu5  :  4,0 us,  0,7 sy,  0,0 ni, 90,1 id,  5,3 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st

KiB Mem:  32985292 total, 25834636 used,  7150656 free,    38312 buffers
KiB Swap: 58592252 total,  1767420 used, 56824832 free.    37988 cached Mem

PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND

7615 asterisk  20   0 3147628 2,813g   1820 S  69,8  8,9   5:35.84 php
 2389 asterisk  20   0 **20,150g 1,207g**   2176 S  28,5  3,8 247:42.19 **asterisk**
  976 mysql     20   0 1411844  19392   2624 S   1,3  0,1  15:13.28 mysqld
21651 root      20   0   24876   2824   2316 R   0,7  0,0   0:02.08 top
...

Comment: You can have a lot of free memory, but when a program allocates memory it needs to be *contiguous*. If there is no contiguous block large enough, the allocation fails.

Comment: -bash-4.3# cat /proc/buddyinfo    
Node 0, zone      DMA      0      1      0      0      2      1      1      0      1      1      3 
Node 0, zone    DMA32    815    785   3993   4256   3637   1256    304    136     93     62    101    
Node 0, zone   Normal  15585  15152  55528  60323  53519  20439   4979   2021    982    721   2081

Answer (score 1):

Your server is using the memory solely for application data. In your top excerpt the buffers and cached are very low. Since asterisk is probably not very disk intensive, that seems fine. But your swap is also being used. This contradicts your assumption that 32GB memory seems enough.

It would be a good idea to install the `sysstat` package to monitor your system on what is really going on. `Top` shows only the current memory and process information. `sysstat` with the included `sar` command records system information every few minutes to retrieve it later for analysis.